# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error reading delta file, spark structured streaming with kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-spark-2.0, spark-structured-streaming, checkpoint

I am using Structured Streaming + Kafka for realtime data analytics in our project. I am using Spark 2.2, kafka 0.10.2.

I am facing an issue during streaming query recovery from checkpoint at application startup. As there are multiple streaming queries derived from a single kafka streaming point and there are different checkpint directories for every streaming query. So in case of job failure, when we restart the job there are some streaming queries which fails to recover from checkpoint location hence throw an exception of  *Error reading delta file*. Here are the logs :

---

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 13.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 831, ip-172-31-10-246.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 3): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error reading delta file /checkpointing/wifiHealthPerUserPerMinute/state/0/2/1.delta of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=2), dir = /checkpointing/wifiHealthPerUserPerMinute/state/0/2]: /checkpointing/wifiHealthPerUserPerMinute/state/0/2/1.delta does not exist
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$updateFromDeltaFile(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:410)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:359)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:359)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:358)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:358)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:360)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:359)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:359)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:358)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:358)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:360)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:359)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:359)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:358)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:358)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:360)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:359)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:359)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:358)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:358)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:360)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:359)
```

---

Please help me out for the same. There may be workarounds for this issue, please suggest me if any, or may be it is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

What's your checkpoint location? This is usually because you are using the local file system to store checkpoints. Make sure you set the "checkpointLocation" option and it points to a distributed file system (such as HDFS) that can be accessed by all nodes. [1]

[1] http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#recovering-from-failures-with-checkpointing

Comment: I have the same issue. My checkpoint location is in Google cloud storage which can be accessed by all the nodes. Still I face this issue. What would be the problem?

Comment: I had the same situation. Switching from local filesystem to hdfs worked for me. But if you ask me, using local filesystem for checkpointing must either work or be technically forbidden in case it's not supported. At the moment, a local path for checkpointing is supported but does not really work. This is not really a good solution.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue and my checkpoint location is AWS S3 Still appearing the same issue. What would be the possible root cause?

Comment: I'm having similar issues with the checkpoint on AWS S3, any ideas on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a production pipeline with checkpoints on AWS S3. I have exactly same issue as people have noted here. After reading the logs I realised it was caused by a dynamic change in sql.shuffle.partitions value during execution. Since I passed this value to a repartition in dataframe, the dataframe repartition was altered between execution - an operation that is not advised by Spark - leading to loss of an executor writing the necessary file.

Unfortunately, rebuilding the pipeline from a new checkpoint as advised by Spark is not possible. The data is so big that we could not afford to reprocess from scratch.

How I solved it:

1. I deleted the failed offset
2. I created the unexisting .delta file from the last successful .delta file
3. My pipeline is running a merge operation but if not I’d have looked for other ways to prevent duplication at target
4. I verify the last file in checkpoint/sources is what I wanted
5. I rerun the pipeline. This made the pipeline to redo the last successful operation including the failed operations. Since my pipeline was a merge operation everything was fine.

Spark needs to add a way that users can recover from scenarios like this. All blogs and articles I read simply provided no solution.

Comment: AWS s3 is not a real filesystem; you can't expect normal log-by-append checkpointing to work. Apache Spark is an open source project which depends on contributions. It is not fair to say "Spark needs to add" and expect it to appear unless you are offering to implement it.