# Spark Structured Streaming: Error reading delta file with hdfs checkpoint location

Tags: spark-structured-streaming, checkpointing

I want to run a Spark Structured Streaming job locally on a single machine. Unfortunately, recovering from an aborted job does not work when the job was aborted while processing data (it fails with the log shown below).

(If the streaming job is aborted while waiting for new data, recovery works and checkpoint data is read correctly).

[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error reading delta file, spark structured streaming with kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46704237/java-lang-illegalstateexception-error-reading-delta-file-spark-structured-stre) indicates that the reason might be that the local filesystem instead of HDFS is used to store checkpoints, however, checkpoint data is stored in HDFS in this case.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error reading delta file hdfs://localhost:9000/user/test/state/0/117/1.delta of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0,part=117),dir = hdfs://localhost:9000/user/test/state/0/117]: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/test/state/0/117/1.delta does not exist
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$updateFromDeltaFile(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcVJ$sp(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:384)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:383)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:383)
    at scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.foreach(NumericRange.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:383)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:535)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.loadMap(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.getStore(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStore$.get(StateStore.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStoreRDD.compute(StateStoreRDD.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /user/test/state/0/117/1.delta
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirStatAndListingOp.getBlockLocations(FSDirStatAndListingOp.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1829)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:709)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:871)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:817)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2606)

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor51.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocksAndGetLastBlockLength(DFSInputStream.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSInputStream.java:272)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSInputStream.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:1526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Hdfs.open(Hdfs.java:315)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Hdfs.open(Hdfs.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.open(AbstractFileSystem.java:628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$6.next(FileContext.java:795)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$6.next(FileContext.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.open(FileContext.java:797)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileContextBasedCheckpointFileManager.open(CheckpointFileManager.scala:322)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$updateFromDeltaFile(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:424)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.FileNotFoundException): File does not exist: /user/test/state/0/117/1.delta
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirStatAndListingOp.getBlockLocations(FSDirStatAndListingOp.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1829)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:709)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:871)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:817)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2606)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1226)
    ... 51 more
```

It would be great if someone would know the reason for that.